# SMTP connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

Tags: smtp, gmail, node.js

I am writing an SMTP client in node.js. I successfully tested it against an SMTP server running on my localhost. However I found out that I am unable to connect to gmail's servers. Trying it with telnet, I run into the same problem.

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 587
```

hangs, and never responds. I do get a response on smtp.gmail.com, but that does not appear to be what I want. What am I doing wrong, and how can I implement it properly.

--Update--

To make it clear, I am sending an email to a gmail account, from my own smtp server

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"?  Is telnet failing to connect?

Comment: No data is transferred, and after a while the connection closes

Comment: Gmail does not support Telnet for security reasons. It uses encrypted protocols like HTTPS for communication. Telnet is not a secure method to access email services, and attempting to use it with Gmail is not recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not getting any response whatsoever it is likely to be your ISP blocking outbound port 25 connections. This is fairly common and is a technique for stopping botnet spam on consumer networks. See the MAAWG document on [Managing Port 25](http://www.maawg.org/sites/maawg/files/news/MAAWG_Port25rec0511.pdf).

Send from a real host - an Amazon EC2 server will work.

Also for sending mail inbound to Gmail, you want port 25, not 587.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any way to get around this without deploying it to a server? It would be much easier for testing purposes

Comment: For the record, it depends on your internet service provider, but some of them enable you to unblock this from your administration interface

Answer (score 1):

Gmails SMTP servers require STARTTLS on port 587 or TLS on port 465.  You will have to authenticate.

I suggest you take a look at the [official gmail documentation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287), and some [code examples](https://github.com/weaver/node-mail) of how others have implemented [sending mail via SMTP](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sending-emails-in-node)/Gmail using Node.

Comment: I am not trying to send an email using gmail's smtp servers, but rather send an email to a gmail address

Comment: @Zwade Then you should be using port 25, and connecting to the servers listed in the `MX` DNS entry of `gmail.com` instead of hardcoding the primary in your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

https://medium.com/cuonghuynh/login-gmail-via-command-line-openssl-8f5545b61e3b